# Checkbox Check changed event firing twice C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a listview with checkbox. According to my requirement I uncheck through javascript. But because of that script my Checkchanged event fires twice and returns the previous unchecked(through javascript) value on second time fires.

Also usually any operation check box triggers an event. But if you check the same item which is unchecked through javascript just before is not fires the checkedchanged event.

I am not sure why is it happening when using script.

Please find the code below

**JavaScript**

```
function CallConfirmBox() {
    alert("456");
    if (confirm('Schedule more than one time slot for the same day will overwrite the file')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        var id = document.getElementById('<%= hdnValue.ClientID%>').value;
        alert(id);
        $('#' + id).attr('checked', false);
        alert("123")
        id = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void chkCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkCheck = (CheckBox)sender;
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)chkCheck.NamingContainer;
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)item;
        string lookupId = lvLookup.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
        hdnValue.Value = chkCheck.ClientID;
        if (lookupMstVal == "ScheduledTime." && lbCheckedIdList.Items.Count > 0 && chkCheck.Checked)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "CallConfirmBox", "CallConfirmBox();", true);//" + chkCheck.ClientID + "
        }

        if (chkCheck.Checked)
            lbCheckedIdList.Items.Add(lookupId);
        else
            lbCheckedIdList.Items.Remove(lookupId);
        hdfLookupId.Value = "";
        foreach (ListItem itm in lbCheckedIdList.Items)
        {
            hdfLookupId.Value += (hdfLookupId.Value == "" ? "" : ",") + itm.Value;
        }
        postbackFlag = true;
    }
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: check your onClick="return CallConfirmBox();"

Comment: There is no onClick on my checkbox. I am calling javascript function from code behind. Please check the if condition from the code behind. @Sailor

Comment: I tried this on a new WebForm with just one button (Button1)

           protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), 
                 "UniqueID","alert('This pops up')", true);
            }

As @Tim said try to find string "_postBack" in the javascript of your page.